# How to open a specific section of a Cognito form?

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to enter a specific section of a Cognito form. For example, I have this published form: https://www.cognitoforms.com/NMA3/BasicContactFormTest

Now, what I would like to do is to generate an URL that open a specific section, "SectionWanted" is the name of the section with a specific response for the question named 'Question'.

Is that possible?

Comment: We would like to gather a bit more information about your use case. Can you contact us via our Support Request (https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Cognito Support, for this kind of questions you should contact them using: https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/